# Bind an ASP.NET TreeView to SqlDataSource using an XML query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, treeview

Is it possible to use a SQL query that returns XML, in order to bind a TreeView control to SQL data?  In other words, I would like to set up a query that presents table data as hieracrhical XML, and bind this XML to the TreeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you assuming to bind TreeView to [XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx) ([XmlHierarchicalDataSourceView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmlhierarchicaldatasourceview.aspx))?

You can implement your own [IHierarchicalDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicaldatasource.aspx) and [HierarchicalDataSourceView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hierarchicaldatasourceview.aspx) for that. I thinks this solution would be better than returning XML from DB.

Comment: Hmm, I was actually being lazy and trying to avoid my own implementation, but I will look at those, thanks.